# Dynamically create arrays and push multiple elements into it in the content of a single loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying loop through a large chunk of data and dynamically create a new hashed object with the value being a new array with multiple objects in the array.

```
let hash = {};

    data.map(x => {
      hash[x.DateOut] = new Array();
      return hash[x.DateOut].push(x);
    });
```

or

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      hash[data[i].DateOut] = []; // Or new Array()
      hash[data[i].DateOut].push(data[i]);
    }
```

I want to avoid declaring each key:value pair individually as it's a large chunk of data, and I want to avoid making multiple for loops if at all possible.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem is here, how are you pushing in Object, you can't use `push()` on Object, you can only use it on array.  you change your code `let hash = []`'

Comment: @BloodyLogic: The code is correct. He's creating an object where all properties are arrays. And to dynamically access every property you can use the array notation.

Answer (score 1):

A fast version checks if the hash exists and take a variable for the key.

```
var key, object;
for (object of data) {
    key = object.DateOut;
    if (!hash[key]) hash[key] = [];
    hash[key].push(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about the initial creating of the array and afterwards pushing you can use this code:

```
for (obj of data) {
      hash[obj.DateOut] = hash[obj.DateOut] || [];
      hash[obj.DateOut].push(obj);
    }
```

Example: https://codepen.io/auskennfuchs/pen/aeWdKY

Comment: The goal is to push multiple items in an array, those code will only return an array with the last item that matched the object key as the arrays value.

Comment: No it's not. See my simple example. It's the same as Nina Scholz posted, but it's using a shorter, simpler syntax.

Comment: it is shorter, but the default check is slower than an `if` statement.

Comment: @Auskennfuchs apologies, you're correct that it does solve the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NinaScholz: Almost. It's not the default check but the of-loop instead of the normal iteration. I've updated my code. Comparison here: https://codepen.io/auskennfuchs/pen/gVWPqO

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way without creating a single variable inside loop could be:

```
let hash = {};
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!hash[data[i].DateOut]) {
      hash[data[i].DateOut] = [data[i]];
    }
    else {
      hash[data[i].DateOut] = [...hash[data[i].DateOut], data[i]];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)